# EF Core stored procedure different returning result

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBooksByAuthor2]
AS
    SELECT 
        books.Id, authors.Name AS Author, books.Name AS Book 
    FROM
        dbo.Authors authors
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.AuthorsBooks authorsBooks ON authors.Id = authorsBooks.AuthorId
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Books books ON books.Id = authorsBooks.BookId
GO
```

In SQL Server Management Studio, result looks like this:

```
Id| Author       | Book
--+--------------+----------
1 | FirstAuthor  | GoodBook1
2 | FirstAuthor  | GoodBook2
3 | FirstAuthor  | GoodBook3
1 | SecondAuthor | GoodBook1
3 | SecondAuthor | GoodBook3
```

In EF Core I added a view model for my stored procedure

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Book { get; set; }
}
```

and I also added something like this to the context class:

```
public partial class StrangeContext : DbContext
{
     public virtual DbSet<BookViewModel> Books2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then I invoke it in a controller action

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAuthors()
{
    var result = db.Books2.FromSql("GetBooksByAuthor2").ToList();
    return new JsonResult(result);
}
```

Result of Json look like

```
[
    { "id": 1, "author":"FirstAuthor", "book":"GoodBook1"},
    { "id": 2, "author":"FirstAuthor", "book":"GoodBook2"},
    { "id": 3, "author":"FirstAuthor", "book":"GoodBook3"}, 
    { "id": 1, "author":"FirstAuthor", "book":"GoodBook1"}, 
    { "id": 3, "author":"FirstAuthor", "book":"GoodBook3"}
]
```

What I am doing wrong? Wrong ViewModel? Where is SecondAuthor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined the `Id` of your `BookViewModel` as the **Key** and as such, Entity Framework caches the first time it queries the 'FirstAuthor' with the `Id` of **1**. The second time it encounters the `Id` 1, it uses the current context and fills the entity based on the cached value.

The problem here is your equivocal model. How can `FirstAuthor` and `SecondAuthor` both have the `Id` = 1.

You could remove the **Key** attribute in your model, but it might lead to confusion, wherever you display these results and once you will want to save any of these entities, you will get unpredictable results.

You could also try `AsNotracking()` but I would strongly advise against it, as you will have troubles once you try to track or save changes. Instead, adjust your stored procedure to return unique IDs for unique rows.

Comment: The proper way would be to return **both** primary keys from the stored procedure query - both the `Authors.Id` as well as the `Books.Id`. Then EF could tell these things apart ....

Comment: There are multiple solutions. If both entities `Book` and `Author` exist, he could query books and include authors, applying a projection and he wouldn’t need any SP. He could also use a composite key. The important part is that the key needs to be unique for EF, the rest is implementation detail, but I can edit the answer and give an example if that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined `Id` in `BookViewModel` class as a key but you're passing non-unique values:

add `authorsBooks.Id` to your SQL query and pass it to `[Key]` in you class and define another field to display `BookId` in both your query and class.

The code would be like this:

```
public class BookViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string Book { get; set; }
}
```

And you'd better write your procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBooksByAuthor2]
AS
    SELECT 
        AB.Id AS id, B.Id AS bookId, 
        A.[Name] AS author, B.[Name] AS book 
    FROM
        dbo.AuthorsBooks AS AB
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Books B ON AB.BookId = B.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Authors A ON A.Id = AB.AuthorId
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

As the Sp return have multiple entries with same Id.
Instead of using DbSet use DbQuery in the DbContext registration for the above given table entity. Use will get the data.
Note : DbQuery do not support key as any property remove the key attribute for Id.